# Consolidate libraries in Windows Media Center (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-center, libraries

I have several hard drives, internal and external, which contain divx and dvd rips that I wish to access from WMC (Windows Media Center).

I've added directories from these drives to the libraries in WMC, and all works fine.  However if I want to watch a certain movie, I need to remember on which drive it is, and go into the correct directory in the WMC library.

Ideally I would like to have one "view" into all of my directories.  For example, opening up a library and seeing all my movies from all my drives consolidated into one list.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?  I was hoping that the new Windows 7 "libraries" feature would solve this, however you cannot add Windows 7 Libraries to WMC Libraries.

Any advice would be apprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The **[Win7 Library Tool](http://zornsoftware.talsit.info/?p=3)** can create shortcuts (actually symoblic links) to the libraries on the System Drive (normally the C: drive), in a \Libraries folder.

> Create a mirror of all libraries
>   (using symbolic links) in
>   [SystemDrive]:\libraries.  This means
>   you can reference all your files using
>   a much shorter path, and also provides
>   another entry-point to your files in
>   many places in the Operating System
>   (e.g. file open/save dialogs).

[image]

You can use these shortcuts in Windows Media Center to point to your libraries.

[image]

Comment: I liked where you were going with this one, but I had some strange results. I created the symbolic links from the tool. But when I look at the contents of the symbolic linked folders, they are empty.  Looked with WMC, explorer, and DOS and they are all shown as empty. Going directly to the libraries in explorer shows them with their valid content.  So didn't seem to work for me. Giving you a +1 because might work for others. – benjwarner 3 mins ago  [delete this comment]

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me :-/

Answer (score 1):

Mine also showed blank folders in the symbolic links. However, I fixed this by running the Win Library Tool with admin rights (right click on the .exe and select Run as administrator).